# codeigniter Missing value file name in db

Tags: php, codeigniter, file, upload

I have a problem with update in my db the value of file upload

My controller

```
public function c_piloti_update()
    {
        // Modifica i valori scheda pilota
        $id= $this->input->post('id');
        $data = array(
            'nominativo' => $this->input->post('nominativo'),
            'fotografia' => $this->input->post('fotografia')
        );

        $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/avatar/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']             = 1000;


        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('fotografia'))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->model('alfa/alfa_model');
            $this->piloti_model->alfa_update($id,$data);            
            redirect('alfa/alfa-edit/'.$id);        
        }

    }
```

My Model

```
public function alfa_update($id, $data)
{       
    $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'));  
    $this->db->update('register', $data);  
}
```

The attachment is saved, but in the DB i haven't the file name.
thanks

Comment: maybe you should replace `$this->input->post('id')` with `$id`, I'm not sure if the Model has access to post data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get File details using this  :  `$this->upload->data();`

```
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('fotografia'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data['image_name '] = $this->upload->data('file_name'); 
       //here image_name is column name in table
        $this->load->model('alfa/alfa_model');
        $this->piloti_model->alfa_update($id,$data);            
        redirect('alfa/alfa-edit/'.$id);        
    }
```

**see this :**

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-upload-directory

Change model method `alfa_update()` to this :

```
   public function alfa_update($id, $data)
   {       
     $this->db->where('id',$id);  
     $this->db->update('register', $data);  
   }
```

Comment: $data['image_name '] = $this->upload->data('file_name'); It Works!!!!!! thanks a lot!!!!